# UIAlertView with UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput: clearing field after regain activity

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have `UIAlertView` with `UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput` style. It works perfect. But when application resign active, and then regain active, then text previously typed into text input... is still visible. But when i'm trying to append some next char, all previous text is suddenly gone. 
what may be reason of this behavior, and how to change it?

Comment: Now when regain active text should appear or clear as per to you?

Comment: @Manohar when regain active text should be clear.

Comment: what do you mean by application lost ?

Comment: application lost (resign) active, and regain active

Comment: Application lost means Did you kill the application or application went into background

Comment: Didn't get my answer ??/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIRST WAY**

**in your ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]init];
    [alert setDelegate:self];
    [alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput];
    [alert show];
}

- (void)setText
{
    UITextField *txt =   [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    [txt setText:@""];
}
```

**in your viewController.h**

**Set the delegate**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate,alerttext>
```

**in your appdelegate.h**

```
@protocol alerttext <NSObject>
- (void)setText;
@end
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    id <alerttext> delegate;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) id <alerttext> delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
@end
```

**in your appDelegate.m**

```
@synthesize delegate;

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.viewController setText];
}
```

**SECOND WAY**

**in your viewcontroller.m**

```
UITextField *text;
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]init];
    [alert setDelegate:self];
    [alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput];
    [alert show];
     text =   [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
}
- (void)setText
{
    [text setText:@""];
}
```

**in your ViewController.h, just declare this method**

```
- (void)setText;
```

**in your appdelegate.m just place this**

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.viewController setText];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the default behavior of `UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput`.

The functionality is similar in `UITextField` having property `secureTextEntry` set to `YES`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: @Thaven: ASFAIK, no way. Or you need to implement a custom control